# Animate has a delay and does not work properly

Tags: animation

When I run this command I don't see anything until the value of a is nearly 0.5

```
 Animate[ RegionPlot[  y^2 < a , {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}] , {a, 0.1, 0.5}]
```

Same situation with Manipulate.

Comment: What happens when you give a step size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building the [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) is too slow.  Use [`Region`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html) along with [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

reg[a_] = ImplicitRegion[y^2 < a, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}}];

Animate[
 Region[reg[a], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}],
 {a, 0.1, 0.5}]
```

[image]